# The fastest way to parse dates in Python when reading .csv file?

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file that has 2 separate columns for `'Date'` and `' Time'`. I read the file like this:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['Date', 'Time'])
```

But it seems that only the `' Date'` column is in time format while the `'Time'` column is still string or in a format other than time format.

When I do the following:

```
data0 = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data0['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data0['Date'])
data0['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data0['Time'])
```

It gives a dataframe I want, but takes quite some time.
So what's the fastest way to read in the file and convert the date and time from a string format?

The .csv file is like this:

```
              Date      Time      Open       High       Low     Close  
0       2004-04-12    8:31 AM  1139.870  1140.860  1139.870  1140.860       
1       2005-04-12   10:31 AM  1141.219  1141.960  1141.219  1141.960       
2       2006-04-12   12:33 PM  1142.069  1142.290  1142.069  1142.120       
3       2007-04-12    3:24 PM  1142.240  1143.140  1142.240  1143.140       
4       2008-04-12    5:32 PM  1143.350  1143.589  1143.350  1143.589
```

Thanks!

Comment: It helps to give an example of your csv. Maybe the first 10 lines or something.

Comment: BTW, the date is in yyyy-mm-dd format, and the time is in a format like: 9:31 AM or 3:31 PM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here, In your case '**Time**' is in **AM/PM** format which take more time to parse.

You can add **format** to increase speed of to_datetime() method.

```
data0=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

# %Y - year including the century
# %m - month (01 to 12)
# %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
data0['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data0['Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d")

# %I - hour, using a -hour clock (01 to 12)
# %M - minute
# %p - either am or pm according to the given time value
# data0['Time']=pd.to_datetime(data0['Time'], format="%I:%M %p") -> around 1 sec
data0['Time']=pd.datetools.to_time(data0['Time'], format="%I:%M %p")
```

For more methods info : [Pandas Tools](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/tools.py)

For more format options check - [datetime format directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

For 500K rows it improved speed from around 60 seconds -> 0.01 seconds in my system.

You can also use :

```
# Combine date & time directly from string format
pd.Timestamp(data0['Date'][0] + " " + data0['Time'][0])
```

Comment: Excellent this will help me a lot.