# Export SAS lib to csv with correct date format (in CSV file)

Tags: python, pandas, sas, export-to-csv

I use:
Python 3.7
SAS v7.1 Eterprise

I want to export some data (from library) from SAS to CSV. After that I want to import this CSV to Pandas Dataframe and use it.
I have problem, because when I export data from SAS with this code:

```
proc export data=LIB.NAME

outfile='path\to\export\file.csv'
dbms=csv
replace;
run;
```

Every column were exported correctly instead of Column with Date. In SAS I see something like:

```
06NOV2018
16APR2018
```

and so on... In CSV it looks the same. But if i import this CSV to DataFrame, unfortunatelly, Python see the column with date as Object/string instead of date type.

**So here is my question**. How Can I export whole library to CSV from SAS with correct type of column (ecpessially column with Date). Maybe I should convert something before Export? Plz help me with this, In SAS I'm new, i want to just import Data from it and use it in Python.

Before you write something, keep in mind, that I had tried with pandas read_sas function, but during this command I've got such Exception with error:

```
df1 = pd.read_sas(path)
```

> ValueError: Unexpected non-zero end_of_first_byte Exception ignored
>   in: 'pandas.io.sas._sas.Parser.process_byte_array_with_data' Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "pandas\io\sas\sas.pyx", line 31, in
>   pandas.io.sas._sas.rle_decompress

I put fillna function and show the same error :/

```
df = pd.DataFrame.fillna((pd.read_sas(path)), value="")
```

I tried with sas7bdat module in Python, but I've got the same error.
Then I tried with sas7bdat_converter module. But CSV has the same values in Date column, so problem  with dtype will arrive after convert csv to DataFrame.

Have you got any sugestions? I've spent 2 days tried to figure it out, but without any positive results :/

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645733/the-fastest-way-to-parse-dates-in-python-when-reading-csv-file?rq=1   Or are you asking how to use the FORMAT statement in SAS code?

Comment: Hopefully, *path* variable is not the `.csv` file but the `.sas7bdat` file. If so, use `read_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `read_sas` error, a [Git issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20940) has been reported but closed for lack of reproducible example. However, I can easily import SAS data files with Pandas using `.sas7bdat` files generated from SAS 9.4 base (possibly the v7.1 Enterprise is the issue).

However, consider using *parse_dates* argument of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) as it can convert your date `DDMMMYY` format to datetime during import. No  change needed with your SAS exported dataset.

```
sas_df = pd.read_csv(r"path\to\export\file.csv", parse_dates = ['DATE_COLUMN'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a unnormal way.

You can export the file into a DTA file (data format from STATA), this is a well defined file type that can store the type of variables and only a little efficiency lost. (obviously, DTA file is larger than CSV file since CSV file is just spliting the variables through ",")

Here is an example.

## How you export from SAS?

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.dataset_to_export
            OUTFILE= "D:\dataset.dta" 
            DBMS=STATA REPLACE;
RUN;
```

## how you import to python?

```
df = pd.read_stata(r"D:\dataset.dta")
```

I believe this will work for you problem.